# add foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I am upgrading my database from mssql to mysql, I am struct on creating foreign keys

> In MSSQL I was using

```
alter table ac_master add constraint 'ac_master_table_conf' foreign key (ac_code) references table_conf (ac_code)
```

MySql is giving error on this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''ac_master_table_conf' foreign key (ac_code) references
>   table_conf(ac_code)' at line 1

Comment: You apparently hit "Submit" before pasting the error message. Please note that Stack Overflow allows to edit questions.

Comment: @Mandeep Singh what is the error given?

Comment: question is updated with error

Comment: Don't use single quotes, use the ` character to wrap the constraint name.

Comment: I have checked without ' character but the problem is same

Comment: It can't be the same error message.

Comment: The problem is Solved by removing the ' character

Comment: thank you all for giving time for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around your constraint name e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE ac_master ADD CONSTRAINT ac_master_table_conf FOREIGN KEY (ac_code) REFERENCES table_conf (ac_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, neither SQL Server nor MySQL use single quote syntax for identifiers. You probably want `ac_master_table_conf` rather than `'ac_master_table_conf'`.

Other than that, [the `ALTER TABLE` syntax is documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html), you don't need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

no quotes are involved in mysql if it is a name of a field or a table.
the only need of quotes is to specify a string as below

```
select * from abc where column = 'string';
```

so be careful next time.